# How to receive event from bus from a non-UI class

Tags: java, android, event-bus

When posting an event on an `EventBus` how can I process it from a class that is not part of any UI?
I.e. post the event receivers process it (UI updated) but also another class that is like a “background” class can get the event and do some “housekeeping”.
I understand that I would need to do something like : `EventBus.getDefault().register(this);` but that would imply that my listener has been loaded explicitly somehow.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can configure the delivery thread with an annotation. http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/delivery-threads-threadmode/

Comment: @Christopher:But how would the class be loaded? Is there a way to somehow init a listener?

Comment: As far as I know, EventBus does not create an instance of your class. You have to do it by yourself. A background service might work for you. Or a Dagger-Singleton.

Comment: @Christopher:So can't put something in the manifest?

Comment: Nope. Maybe a (local) broadcast receiver will suite your problem better? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html